# squirrel-sql : no sequence options

Tags: squirrel-sql

I've installed Squirrle and connect to DB2.

Yet in my install I don't get the tree node for "sequences".

I get...

ALIAS

- HIERARCHY TABLE
- INOPERATIVE VIEW
- MATERIALIZED QUERY
- NICKNAME
- SYSTEM TABLE
- TYPED TABLE
- TYPED VIEW
- VIEW
- PROCEDURE
- UDT

I'm missing the next one called "SEQUENCE".

I've uninstalled/reinstalled, but I still cant see it.

Anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you install the optional DB2 plugin ?

Comment: I was convinced I'd check that box each time. I've just tried another install (number 4) and it works!